# How do I remove the timestamp from a vivado bitstream?

Tags: vivado

When generating bitstreams with Vivado, the resulting file contains the timestamp of when the bitstream was generated.  This timestamp makes it difficult to compare bitstreams (to see whether they are identical) without editing the bitstream file in a hex editor.  [Others](https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D52E00007DGda6SAD/how-do-i-remove-the-time-stamp-from-from-a-bit-file?language=en_US) have proposed solutions that involve generating the ".bin" file instead of the ".bit" file, but that leaves off the UserID (and presumably other information stored in the header).

Answer (score 0):

## Modify the bitstream (after generation) using TCL

If you do not already have a bitstream generated then generate the bitstream using the open design:

```
set bitstream system_wrapper.bit
write_bitstream -force $bitstream
```

The bitstream header format is relatively simple, so you can use TCL to replace the timestamp in the bitstream with a constant timestamp (this example uses the Unix Epoch, 1970/01/01 00:00:00):

```
set h [open $bitstream "r+"]
fconfigure $h -translation binary
set offset 0xE
seek $h $offset
binary scan [read $h 2] S len
set offset [expr {$offset + 1 + $len + 2}]
seek $h $offset
binary scan [read $h 2] S len
set offset [expr {$offset + 1 + $len + 2}]
seek $h $offset
binary scan [read $h 2] S len
seek $h [expr {$offset + 2}]
puts -nonewline $h [clock format 0 -gmt 1 -format %Y/%m/%d]
set offset [expr {$offset + 1 + $len + 2}]
seek $h $offset
binary scan [read $h 2] S len
seek $h [expr {$offset + 2}]
puts -nonewline $h [clock format 0 -gmt 1 -format %H:%M:%S]
close $h
```

Now you can easily compare bitstreams with md5sum without manually editing the bitstream files.